# Basics on setting up a hyper-v cluser on a Windows 8 host

Tags: hyper-v, cluster, failovercluster, windows-cluster

I'm a complete newbie to setting up servers and clustering, so baby gloves please :)

I am trying to simulate a cluster of 4 nodes on my windows 8 laptop using hyper-v (its a beefy laptop, so don't worry about the performance). So far, I have done the following steps:

1) Installed a VM (Windows Server 2012) to act as my domain controller

2) Installed 4 VM's (each with Windows Server 2012) to act as my cluster. Each VM is connected to the domain

3) Installed the Failover cluster feature on each of the 4 nodes and created a cluster using the Failover cluster Manager

Now, I need to setup a storage for this cluster. My initial thoughts were to use a shared folder from my laptop which can act as a common storage, but I can't figure out how to do this or even if this is possible. I keep hearing about setting up iSCSI but I have failed to find a basic tutorial on this.

I did also find iSCSI software target (http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=19867), but I'm not sure how to use this. Should I install WS2012 on a new VM, join it to the domain and install this software on that VM in order to provide storage for my cluster? IF so, will I need to recreate my cluster?

Seeking help from one of the gurus on this forum on how to take this forward and configure a common storage for the cluster in the simplest manner possible. Just as a tiny bit of background, I need to do this in order to test out some cluster related runbooks from system center orchestrator, so this cluster won't really be used for anything real.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: link bomb this is for guest clustering, you can't do host clustering with windows 8. http://blogs.technet.com/b/mghazai/archive/2009/12/12/hyper-v-guest-clustering-step-by-step-guide.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that link. I found another great step-by-step guide to setting up shared storage, but that doesn't work with in my setup http://clusteringformeremortals.com/2012/12/31/windows-server-2012-clustering-step-by-step/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now managed to do the above using information from a variety of links.
Adding these links here for completeness:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sainfrateam/archive/2011/05/09/hyper-v-guest-clustering.aspx
http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2012/03/30/installing-and-configuring-target-iscsi-server-on-windows-server-8-beta.aspx

Hope someone else can find the post useful

Comment: Found the definitive guide to doing what I want to do, again if it helps someone, look here http://blogs.technet.com/b/babulalghule/archive/2013/02/16/how-to-configure-two-node-windows-server-2012-cluster-on-virtual-machines-for-testing.aspx